# Cordova 2.3.0 Open links in Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I know this has been asked a lot, but i tried almost anything I could find here and nothing helps.
I want to open links with class "external" in native iOS browser, but i'm not able to manage it.
Here is what I tried:

```
$('.external').live('click', function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();                      
    var url = $(this).attr('href');             
    loadURL(url);                               
})   

function loadURL(url){
    var ref = window.open(url, '_system');
}
```

As of phonegap documentation, it should now open the link in system webbrowser, but it always uses the InAppBrowser, no matter of the link-target.
I also set "OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" to false in config.xml. No change.

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check that your click handler is actually being invoked? If you put the code that attaches the event handler in the wrong location(i.e. in onDeviceReady(), then the click handler will not be invoked) -> the links will always be opened inside of the app. Also I am using jquery ".on" since ".live" has been removed in jquery 1.9; which I was using for my test.

I just tested the following code on Cordova 2.4.0, and it works. Here is some important code excerpts:

HTML portion:

```
  <a class=".external" href="http://www.google.com">Go to external page</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT portion:

```
    function loadURL(url){
        var ref = window.open(url, '_system');
    }

    $(function(){

      $('.external').on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
         loadURL(url);
      });

    });
```

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't help at all, because as I wrote in my startpost, I also tried to set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to false. But it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see. I am still using Cordova 1.9; which is why it works for me. I just looked at the available properties for config.xml @ http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20iOS , and it looks like OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView is NOT an option anymore...

Comment: Hm, true. I guess that is because of the InAppBrowserthing, which is new since 2.3.0: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: I checked, and you are doing everything correctly with "window.open(url, '_system');".  I wonder if this is a bug in phonegap 2.3. Have you tried upgrading to phonegap 2.4; just to check if it works there?